# distinguish between two different kinds of string and extract them

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a column of notes in excel that has notes like "**01/16 14:38 ATND [Notes from Dealer/Distributor] JR**" and "**01/16 14:14 ATND [Notes from Company] JR2**" and "**01/16 14:14 ATND [Notes from Company] TLO The item is back ordered**"

As you can see after the bracket sign, there is a two letter or three letter codes of three different variations, JR, JR2 and TLO. I wrote a program that only distinguishes between JR and TLO but wont extract the code if its numbered for example, JR and JR2. If someone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
Sub G_ExtractCodes()

Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long
Dim NoteCodes As Range

For i = LR To 2 Step -1

Set NoteCodes = Range("O" & i)

If InStr(NoteCodes, "JR") >= 1 Then
Cells(i, 20) = "JR"
ElseIf InStr(NoteCodes, "JR2") >= 1 Then
Cells(i, 20) = "JR2"
ElseIf InStr(NoteCodes, "TLO") >= 1 Then
Cells(i, 20) = "TLO"
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Do the codes **always** appear immediately after the right square bracket?

Comment: David, yes they do. They always appear right after square bracket and there are also ones that have no codes in them, in which case I would like the row blank

Comment: Robert see my suggestions below. Cheers.

Comment: I removed the link to the "picture" you mention, because the link is dead... Your picture is unavailable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first condition in the `If` statement is more restrictive than the first `ElseIf` clause, so any instance of "JR2" will be caught by the *first* test (only finds "JR", and the `ElseIf` are not evaluated).

Flip your logic, and I think this should fix it:

```
If InStr(NoteCodes, "JR2") >= 1 Then
    Cells(i, 20) = "JR2"
ElseIf InStr(NoteCodes, "JR") >= 1 Then
    Cells(i, 20) = "JR"
ElseIf InStr(NoteCodes, "TLO") >= 1 Then
    Cells(i, 20) = "TLO"
End If
```

Alternatively, you can parse out the codes like:

```
Dim codeValue as String
Dim bracketLocation as Integer

For i = LR To 2 Step -1

Set NoteCodes = Range("O" & i) 

    'finds the position of the right bracket
    bracketLocation  = Instr(NoteCodes, "]")

    'Lops off any characters up to & including the right square bracket
    codeValue = Trim(Mid(NoteCodes, bracketLocation + 1))

    'removes any text that appears *after* the code value, if any
    If Instr(codeValue, " ") > 0 Then
        codeValue = Left(codeValue, Instr(codeValue, " "))
    End If

    Cells(i, 20).Value = codeValue

    'clear out the variable
    codeValue = vbNullString

Next
```

Comment: @Robert, does this *not* do that? This script should only extract *one* codevalue per cell; whatever appears immediately after the bracket and *only* that much.

Comment: David, I tried this but it doesn't really do anything for some reason.

Comment: Please revise your Q to show what you are currently trying to implement.

Comment: David, do you think the reason its not looping through is because in the code there is no "i" to denote it to check through each single row in column "O"? Just an idea but I might be wrong.

Comment: David, your code works perfectly. I just forgot to defined LR thats why it wasnt doing anything. I am running into another problem however, some of the notes have multiple brackets, how do I make it so it only looks at the left-most bracket?

Comment: The `InstrRev` will return the *right-most* bracket and was fine since I assumed there was only one set of square brackets. Instead, you can use the `Instr` function which hould only return the left-most closing square bracket.

Comment: I've changed the code above to use `Instr` instead. If this has solved your problem, do consider upvoting or accepting the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub G_ExtractCodes()
  sn=cells(1).currentregion.columns(1).offset(,15)

  for j=1 to ubound(sn)
    If InStr(sn(j,1), "JR") Then
      Cells(j, 20) = iif(instr(sn(j,1),"JR2"),"JR2","JR")
    ElseIf InStr(sn(j,1), "TL") Then
      Cells(j, 20) = iif(instr(sn(j,1),"TL0"),"TL0","TL")
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: its giving me an error saying variable not defined. This line is highlighted "sn = Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Offset(, 15)"

Comment: Comment out or delete 'Option Explicit' so you won't be harrassed any longer.